# Take 10 array elements at a time in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
       echo "<table title='mxit:table:full' style='width: 100%' width='100%'><colgroup span='2' width='50%'></colgroup>";




        foreach($arr['chart_data'] as $key => $element){



          echo "<tr>";


            foreach($element as $subkey => $subelement){

              // $subelement =chop($subelement,'DIRECTSegment');

                 if($subkey++ < 2) {
                if($key == 0)
                {

               echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'>$subelement</td>";
                }

                else if($subkey == 1)
                {
                    echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'>$subelement</td>";   
                }

                else
                {

                echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'><a href='getdata.php?key=$key'>".$subelement."</a></td>";
                }
                 }

            }

              }
           echo "</tr>";

       echo "</table>";
```

How do i take only 10 elements of my array $arr['chart_data'] at a time ?

Comment: This is your 6th question today about the same few lines of code - you should really use Google and some tutorials instead of copy pasting everything. Googling "first 10 elements in array php" would give you 28.8 million results.

Comment: i have been trying for a while now this isn't copy paste code i used my own :/

Comment: What conclusion did you come to when searching? `array_slice` which is the ***first*** result on Google would work fine.

Comment: your `$arr['chart_data']` contains sub arrays so, what do you mean by elements?

Comment: I tried array_slice with chart_data array didn't work foe me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway for all those who gave me negative votes and for my own betterment i solved my issue:

Here is what i did:

```
 $totalfiles = count($arr['chart_data']);
  $limit = 10;
  $pages = ceil($totalfiles / $limit);


  if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or!is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
      //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
      $startrow = 0;
      //otherwise we take the value from the URL
  } else {
      $startrow = (int) $_GET['startrow'];
  }

  echo "<table title='mxit:table:full' style='width: 100%' width='100%'><colgroup span='2' width='50%'></colgroup>";


  $data = array_slice($arr['chart_data'], $startrow, 10); // same as offset 0 limit 50 in sql

  foreach($data as $key => $element) {



      echo "<tr>";


      foreach($element as $subkey => $subelement) {

          $subelement = chop($subelement, 'DIRECTSegment');

          if ($subkey++ < 2) {
              if ($key == 0 && $startrow == 0) {

                  echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'>$subelement</td>";
              } else if ($subkey == 1) {
                  echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'>$subelement</td>";
              } else {

                  echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'><a href='getdata.php?key=$key'>".$subelement.
                  "</a></td>";
              }
          }

      }
      echo "</tr>";

  }


  echo "</table>";




  /* free result set */
  $result - > close();
  }


  /* close connection */
  $mysqli - > close();

   //now this is the link..
  echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].
  '?startrow='.($startrow + 10).
  '">Next</a>';

  $prev = $startrow - 10;

   //only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
  if ($prev >= 0)

      echo '  <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].
  '?startrow='.$prev.
  '">Previous</a>';
```

**Implemented paging and using array slice to display 10 elements at a time.**

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

Set a counter, and then `break` the loop when `$count` hits 10.

```
$count = 0;
/* loop here */
if ($count == 10) break;
```

Comment: @AlexandruG. there are multiple ways to do this. Both work the same, one just copies and truncates the array, one just breaks the loop on a condition.

Comment: No reason in -1'ing this. This method wouldn't need to create a copy of the array (which `array_slice` does), so it'd actually be a little faster.

Comment: @h2ooooooo If you need to get x elements from array, why on Earth would you prefer a loop instead of slice ? Do you think that a loop is so memory cheap ? You should run some benchmarks

Comment: @AlexandruG. You should take a look at OP's code. Do you honestly think it's enough to use `array_slice` when OP is *already looping through the results*? Is your suggestion to use `array_slice($array, 0, 10);` as the only line of code? If the question is whether to use a counter (which is similar to `for ($i = 0, $len = min(10, count($array)); $i < $len; $i++)`) or `foreach(array_slice($array, 0, 10) as $item)` then the first is quicker.